# Induction of group von neumann algebra for group homomorphism with amenable kernel

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\alpha:H\to G$ be a  group  homomorphism betwenn  discrete  countable  groups, and  assume  that  the kernel  of  $\alpha$  is  an  amenable  group, denoted  by $K$. I  would  like to  know references for  the  basic  questions:

1. How  does  the  induced  group  homomorphism  between the  group Von Neumann algebras $\mathcal{N}H\to \mathcal{N}G$ look  like?
2. Can  one  define  via this  homomorphism  a  functor  between  the  (algebraic) categories  of  $\mathcal{N}H$  and  $\mathcal{N}G$  modules? Is it  exact in  general  in  any  of  the  approaches  to  homological  algebra  over  von  Neumann  algebras (Farber/Lück)?

I am  aware  of the proof  that  this  functor  is  fully  faithful  in  the  case  that  the  kernel  of the homomorphism  is  trivial  by  work of  W. Lück (Dimension Theory of  arbitrary  modules  over  finite  Von  Neumann  algebras) in J. reine. ang. Math. 495, 1998.

Comment: What do you mean by the "induced group homomorphism" in point 1? A group homomorphism $\alpha : H \rightarrow G$ only extends to a normal $*$-homomorphism between the associated group von Neumann algebras if the kernel of $\alpha$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks  a  lot for  the  comment, the  Group Von Neumann  Algebra   is  only  functorial for homomorphisms  with  finite  kernel,  I  was   asuming wrongly  that  the   functoriality  of  the  reduced  group  C* algebra  goes  over.